# I want to the result print out like this: this is your stamp duty: result. However, i just get the number only, am i wrong some where?

Tags: c#

I want to the result print out like this:

> this is your stamp duty: result.

However, i just get the number only, am i wrong some where?

```
using System;

namespace simple_application
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)    
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is the test for calculate the stamp duty");
            Console.Write("Please enter your value of the vehicle: ");//so i let the input here

            decimal vehicle_value = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

            if (vehicle_value <= 45000)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(vehicle_value / 100 * 3);

                decimal number1 = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine(number1);
                Console.WriteLine("this is your stamp duty: "+ number1); // message + output
            }
            else//if the money greater than 45000
            {
                Console.WriteLine((vehicle_value - 45000) / 100 * 5 + 1350);
                decimal number2 = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("This is your stamp duty: " + number2); // message + output
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the thing is I have tried so many different types of ways to contain a value like int, float, or long but it just not work?

Comment: Tip: Don't use `Convert.ToDecimal`. Always prefer `Decimal.TryParse` instead.

Comment: So I need to change from ToDecimal to TryParse. Thanks you

Answer (score 3):

I think you are calling `Console.ReadLine()` too many times, just calculate the values that you need and output them:

```cs
using System;

namespace simple_application
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is the test for calculate the stamp duty");
            decimal vehicle_value;

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter your value of the vehicle: "); //so i let the input here
            }
            while (!decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out vehicle_value));
            
            if (vehicle_value <= 45000)
            {
                decimal number1 = vehicle_value / 100 * 3;
                Console.WriteLine("this is your stamp duty: " + number1); //message+output
            }
            else //if the money greater than 45000
            {
                decimal number2 = (vehicle_value - 45000) / 100 * 5 + 1350;
                Console.WriteLine("This is your stamp duty: " + number2); //message+output
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also I've replaced `Convert.ToDecimal` by a loop calling `Decimal.TryParse`, so it doesn't fail on invalid input.

Comment: I'll give you an upvote if you change your code to use `Decimal.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToDecimal` ;)

Comment: @Dai done :) also added a loop to call it

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line and the code should work as expected

```
        Console.WriteLine(number1);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the test for calculate the stamp duty");
        Console.Write("Please enter your value of the vehicle: ");//so i let the input here

        decimal vehicle_value = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

        if (vehicle_value <= 45000)
        {
           decimal num1 = vehicle_value / 100 * 3;
           Console.WriteLine("this is your stamp duty: {0}", num1); // message + output
        }
        else//if the money greater than 45000
        {
            decimal num2 = (vehicle_value - 45000) / 100 * 5 + 1350;
            Console.WriteLine("This is your stamp duty: {0}", num2); // message + output
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: When posting an answer, it is customary and polite to spend enough time writing the post to make sure it's formatted in a readable way. Also, the code above does not seem like it a) adds anything useful beyond that already contributed by the other answer, nor b) even would produce output that the author of question might want (why would they want the computed value to be displayed twice? and if they did want it displayed twice, why wouldn't they perform the computation just once, putting the result into a variable, then displaying the value of the _variable_, instead of computing it twice?)

Comment: Finally note that "code dump" answers aren't useful. If you want to post an answer, put enough effort into it to actually _explain_ your answer, showing why the code you may include in your answer not only fixes whatever problem the author of the question has, but why that version of a fix is preferable to some other.